# How to catch,when paragraph breaks by something

Tags: luatex

Maybe there is a way to catch when the paragraph breaks by something, for example a formula to insert some code after the break of the paragraph.
The command `\everypar` allows us to catch when the paragraph is started, but it can also be a way to catch when the paragraph breaks by something, such as a formula with `[]` to insert some code after the break of the paragraph.

Yes, in lua exists a callback post_linebreak_filter which solves this problem, but I need the same for LaTeX/lualatex to insert some LaTeX commands.

Is it possible and if so, how does it work?

Comment: Why can't the formula insert the code?

Comment: Because i must to understand,if formula now inside of the paragraph,or outside. @David-Carlisle If i redefine \everymathdisplay,will i get an error when,for example,i will use equation environment,or not? Because when i before redefine this for solving of problem with $$ and $,i had an errors,when i used it for example with equation environment. In fact,i need in hook,which catch breaking of paragraph by something,not only formula,which will works in all or in most cases.

Comment: You can test for the current tag (`\tagpdfget{mc_tag}`), if it is P you know you are in a paragraph (assuming that your paragraph code is doing the right thing).

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer But i need in catching when paragraph breakes to close mc and struct tag and open another tag depending of situation. Yes,i can create variable in expl3 which shows me,if i in par or not and for formulas with \[\] close mc and struct tags,if i in par,and after that open another tag,but i asked this question with hope,that exists best solution,which allow me to catch,if paragraph breaks by formula,description,itemize,enumerate,etc,to insert my code,when paragraph breaks by something.

Comment: all list environment issue a \par, so should work like any new paragraph command. And for formula you could simply accepts that it is in the par and allow the structure to be a kid of the paragraph.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer I am not sure,that it will be correct according to pdf specification have one struct paragraph inside other struct paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

Not every context that triggers TeX's linebreaking algorithm has a reasonable hook.

The most common cases are the end of a paragraph, so `\par`,  and a math display mid-paragraph (which you can detect with `\everydisplay`) but the tricky case is end of a vbox, if you have `\vbox` (or a wrapper such as a `\parbox` or tabular `p` column) then in a context like

```
\vbox{
\hsize = 1cm
one two three four five}
```

the line breaker is triggered directly by the end of box (unlike say)

```
one two three four\vskip 2cm
```

where the `\vskip` inserts a `\par` token to(hopefully) end the paragraph, so if you hav edefined `\par` to insert your code it will catch this case.

Even in e-TeX there is no user controllable hook that can catch end of vbox, unless you redefine `\vbox` (and `\vtop` etc) to insert code at the end, but redefining `\vbox` while not breaking existing code is hard.